# ZPL Printer virtual Zebra printer Chrome plug-in not printing more than one image

Tags: vba, printing, zebra-printers, zpl-ii

I'm using the "ZPL Printer" chrome plug-in to simulate Zebra printing from VBA. For some reason, I can't get it to print more than one image on the label in the same job. Each image prints correctly when sent in different jobs (print on different labels) but when sent together, only the first image sent gets printed.

```
Print #1, "^XA"
'first image
Print #1, "^FO0,0^GFA,5000,5000,25,,gJ018,gJ03C,gJ07E,gJ0FF,gI01FF8,gI03FFC,gI07FFE,gI0JF,gH01JF8,gH03JFC,gH07JFE,gH0LF,gG01LF8,gG03LFC,gG07LFE,gG0IFE7IF,g01IF"
Print #1, "C3IF8,g03IF81IFC,g07IF00IFE,g0IFE007IF,Y01IFC003IF8,Y03IF8001IFC,Y07IFJ0IFE,Y0IFEJ07IF,X01IFCJ03IF8,X03IF8J01IFC,X07IFL0IFE,X0IFEL07IF,W01IFCL03IF8,W0"
Print #1, "3IF8L01IFC,W07IFN0IFE,W0IFEN07IF,V01IFCN03IF8,V03IF8N01IFC,V07IFP0IFE,V0IFEP07IF,U01IFCP03IF8,U03IF8P01IFC,U07IFR0IFE,U0IFER07IF,T01IFCL08K03IF8,T03IF"
Print #1, "8K018K01IFC,T07IFL018L0IFE,T0IFEL018L07IF,S01IFCL038L03IF8,S03IF8L038L01IFC,S07IFM03CM0IFE,S0IFEM03CM07IF,R01IFCM07CM03IF8,R03IF8M07EM01IFC,R07IFN07EN"
Print #1, "0IFE,R0IFEN07FN07IF,Q01IFCN07FN03IF8,Q03IF8N07F8M01IFC,Q07IFO07F8N0IFE,Q0IFEO07FCN07IF,P01IFCO07FEN03IF8,P03IF8O07FEN01IFC,P07IFP07FFO0IFE,P0IFEL01C00"
Print #1, "7FFO07IF,O01IFCL01E007FF002L03IF8,O03IF8L01F007FF803L01IFC,O07IFM01F007FF803M0IFE,O0IFEM01F807FF8038L07IF,N01IFCM01F807FFC038L03IF8,N03IF8M01FC07FFC03"
Print #1, "CL01IFC,N07IFN01FC07FFC03CM0IFE,N0IFEN03FC0IFE03CM07IF,M01IFCN03FC0IFE03CM03IF8,M03IF8N03FC0IFE07EM01IFC,M07IFO03FC0IFE07EN0IFE,M0IFEO03FE1IFE07EN07IF"
Print #1, ",L01IFCM0803FE1JF07EN03IF8,L03IF8M0C03FF3IFE0FEN01IFC,L07IFN0E03FF3IFE0FEO0IFE,L0IFEN0F03LFE1FEO07IF,K01IFCN0703LFE3FEO03IF8,K03IF8N0783LFE7FE02M01IFC"
Print #1, ",K07IFO07C3OFE03N0IFE,K0IFEO07C3OFE07N07IF,J01IFCO07E3OFE07N03IF8,J03IF8O07F3OFE0F8M01IFC,J07IFP07F9OFE1F8N0IFE,J0IFEP07LF7JFC3F8N07IF,I01IFCP07LF3JFC"
Print #1, "7F8N03IF8,I03IF8P07LF1JFCFF8N01IFC,I07IFQ07LF0JFBFFCO0IFE,I0IFEQ07LF07LFCO07IF,001IFCQ07LF07LFCO03IF8,003IF8Q07LF03LF8O01IFC,007IFR03LF01LF8P0IFE,00IF"
Print #1, "ER03LF01LF8P07IF,01IFCO01003KFE01LF8P03IF8,03IF8O01801KFE00LFQ01IFC,07IFQ0C01KFE00LFR0IFE,0IFEQ0E01KFC00LFR07IF,1IFCQ0F00KFC00KFER03IF83IF8Q0F80KFC007"
Print #1, "JFER01IFC7IFR0FC07JF8007JFC08Q0IFE7IFR07E07JF8007JF808Q0IFE3IF8Q07FE3FF7F8007FDFF818P01IFC1IFCQ07KF7F8007F9FF078P03IF80IFEQ03KF7F8007F9FE3F8P07IF,07IF"
Print #1, "Q03KF3F8007F1JF8P0IFE,03IF8P03JFE1F8007C1JF8O01IFC,01IFCP03JFE0F800781JFP03IF8,00IFEP01JFE07800603JFP07IF,007IFP01KF01800403JFP0IFE,003IF8O01KF0040040"
Print #1, "3JFO01IFC,001IFCP0KFM07JFO03IF8,I0IFEP0KF8L07IFEO07IF,I07IFP0KF8L07IFEO0IFE,I03IF8O0KFCL0JFEN01IFC,I01IFCO07FFBFEK01JFCN03IF8,J0IFEO07FFDFEK01FDFFCN07"
Print #1, "IF,J07IFO03FFC7FK03F9FFCN0IFE,J03IF8N03FFE038J07C3FF8M01IFC,J01IFCN01FFEO03FF8M03IF8,K0IFEN01IFO07FFN07IF,K07IFO0IFO0IFN0IFE,K03IF8N0IF8N0FFEM01IFC,K0"
Print #1, "1IFCN07FF8M01FFCM03IF8,L0IFEN03FFCM03FFCM07IF,L07IFO0FFEM07FF8M0IFE,L03IF8N07FFM0FFEM01IFC,L01IFCN01FF8K01FFCM03IF8,M0IFEO07FCK03FFN07IF,M07IFO01FFK07"
Print #1, "FCN0IFE,M03IF8O03FCI01FFN01IFC,M01IFCQ0FC003F8N03IF8,N0IFEgL07IF,N07IFgL0IFE,N03IF8gJ01IFC,N01IFCgJ03IF8,O0IFEgJ07IF,O07IFgJ0IFE,O03IF8J0UFI01IFC,O01I"
Print #1, "FCJ0UFI03IF8,P0IFEJ0UFI07IF,P07IFJ0UFI0IFE,P03IF8I0UF001IFC,P01IFCI0UF003IF8,Q0IFEg07IF,Q07IFg0IFE,Q03IF8X01IFC,Q01IFCX03IF8,R0IFEX07IF,R07IFX0IFE,R03"
Print #1, "IF8V01IFC,R01IFCV03IF8,S0IFEV07IF,S07IFV0IFE,S03IF8T01IFC,S01IFCT03IF8,T0IFET07IF,T07IFT0IFE,T03IF8R01IFC,T01IFCR03IF8,U0IFER07IF,U07IFR0IFE,U03IF8P01"
Print #1, "IFC,U01IFCP03IF8,V0IFEP07IF,V07IFP0IFE,V03IF8N01IFC,V01IFCN03IF8,W0IFEN07IF,W07IFN0IFE,W03IF8L01IFC,W01IFCL03IF8,X0IFEL07IF,X07IFL0IFE,X03IF8J01IFC,X0"
Print #1, "1IFCJ03IF8,Y0IFEJ07IF,Y07IFJ0IFE,Y03IF8001IFC,Y01IFC003IF8,g0IFE007IF,g07IF00IFE,g03IF81IFC,g01IFC3IF8,gG0IFE7IF,gG07LFE,gG03LFC,gG01LF8,gH0LF,gH07JFE"
Print #1, ",gH03JFC,gH01JF8,gI0JF,gI07FFE,gI03FFC,gI01FF8,gJ0FF,gJ07E,gJ03C,gJ018,,^FS"
'second image
Print #1, "^FO500,500^GFA,5000,5000,25,,gJ018,gJ03C,gJ07E,gJ0FF,gI01FF8,gI03FFC,gI07FFE,gI0JF,gH01JF8,gH03JFC,gH07JFE,gH0LF,gG01LF8,gG03LFC,gG07LFE,gG0IFE7IF,g01IF"
Print #1, "C3IF8,g03IF81IFC,g07IF00IFE,g0IFE007IF,Y01IFC003IF8,Y03IF8001IFC,Y07IFJ0IFE,Y0IFEJ07IF,X01IFCJ03IF8,X03IF8J01IFC,X07IFL0IFE,X0IFEL07IF,W01IFCL03IF8,W0"
Print #1, "3IF8L01IFC,W07IFN0IFE,W0IFEN07IF,V01IFCN03IF8,V03IF8N01IFC,V07IFP0IFE,V0IFEP07IF,U01IFCP03IF8,U03IF8P01IFC,U07IFR0IFE,U0IFER07IF,T01IFCR03IF8,T03IF8R0"
Print #1, "1IFC,T07IFT0IFE,T0IFEK03IFK07IF,S01IFCJ01JFEJ03IF8,S03IF8J07KFJ01IFC,S07IFJ01FE001FCJ0IFE,S0IFEJ03FJ03EJ07IF,R01IFCJ0FCK0F8I03IF8,R03IF8I01FL07CI01IFC"
Print #1, ",R07IFJ03EL03EJ0IFE,R0IFEJ078M0FJ07IF,Q01IFCJ0FN078I03IF8,Q03IF8I01EN03CI01IFC,Q07IFJ03CN01FJ0IFE,Q0IFEJ078O0F8I07IF,P01IFCJ0FP07CI03IF8,P03IF8I01EP03"
Print #1, "EI01IFC,P07IFJ03CQ0FJ0IFE,P0IFEJ0788P078I07IF,O01IFCJ0F1CO023CI03IF8,O03IF8I01E3CO071CI01IFC,O07IFJ01C78O079EJ0IFE,O0IFEJ01C7P03CEJ07IF,N01IFCJ01CEP01"
Print #1, "CEJ03IF8,N03IF8J01CEP01CEJ01IFC,N07IFK01CEQ0EEK0IFE,N0IFEK01CEQ0FCK07IF,M01IFCL0EEQ0FCK03IF8,M03IF8L0FEQ0FCK01IFC,M07IFM0FEP01F8L0IFE,M0IFEM07EP01F8L0"
Print #1, "7IF,L01IFCM03EP01FM03IF8,L03IF8M03FP01FM01IFC,L07IFN01FP03EN0IFE,L0IFEO0FP03CN07IF,K01IFCO0F1FFE001FFE3CN03IF8,K03IF8O0F3IF003IF1CN01IFC,K07IFK03FI0E3"
Print #1, "IF007IF1C001F8J0IFE,K0IFEK07FC00E3IF003IF1C007FCJ07IF,J01IFCK0F7E00E3IF003FFE1C00FDEJ03IF8,J03IF8K0E1F00E1FFE001FFE1C00F0EJ01IFC,J07IFL0E0700E1FFC001F"
Print #1, "FC1C01C0EK0IFE,J0IFEL0E0780E0FFCI0FFC1C03C0FK07IF,I01IFCK03E03C0E07F8I07F81C0780F8J03IF8,I03IF8K03E01E0E03EJ01E01C0F00F8J01IFC,I07IFL07E00F0FP03C1E00F"
Print #1, "CK0IFE,I0IFEL07E007C78J0EJ0787C00FCK07IF,001IFCL07E003F3CI01FJ0F1F800FCK03IF8,003IF8L07CI0FFEI03F8001E7FI06CK01IFC,007IFM07J03FF8003F8007FF8I01CL0IFE,"
Print #1, "00IFEM0707F80FFE003F801FFE01FC1CL07IF,01IFCM071FFC03FF007FC03FF807FF1CL03IF8,03IF8M07JF00FFC07FC0FFE01JFCL01IFC,07IFN03F80FC03FE0FFE1FF807E03F8M0IFE,0"
Print #1, "IFEN01E003F01CF0FFE3CE01F800FN07IF,1IFCS0FC1C70FFE38C07ER03IF83IF8S03F1C38F1E38C1F8R01IFC7IFU0FDC38I038C7ET0IFE7IFU03FC3J038FF8T0IFE3IF8U0FC38I070FET0"
Print #1, "1IFC1IFCU03C3CI0F0F8T03IF80IFEU01C1F003E1EU07IF,07IFV0E0FE0FC1CU0IFE,03IF8T01E07IF83FT01IFC,01IFCT07F01FFE03FCS03IF8,00IFES01FF801E007FFS07IF,007IFS07"
Print #1, "F3CK0F1FCR0IFE,003IF8Q01FC1EJ01E07FQ01IFC,001IFCQ07F03FJ07F80FCP03IF8,I0IFEM0FF03F80FFC001FFE03F81FEL07IF,I07IFL03JFE03FBF807F3F80KF8K0IFE,I03IF8K07JF"
Print #1, "80FE0FF1FC07E03JFCJ01IFC,I01IFCK0780FE03F803IF001F80FE01CJ03IF8,J0IFEK0EK0FEI0FFCI07FK0EJ07IF,J07IFK0E38003FJ01EJ01FC0038EJ0IFE,J03IF8J073800FCQ07E003"
Print #1, "9CI01IFC,J01IFCJ07F801FR01F003FCI03IF8,K0IFEJ03F803CS07803F8I07IF,K07IFK0F8078S03C03EJ0IFE,K03IF8J03C07T01C078I01IFC,K01IFCJ01C07T01C07J03IF8,L0IFEJ01"
Print #1, "C0EU0E07J07IF,L07IFJ01C0EU0E07J0IFE,L03IF8I01C1EU0F07I01IFC,L01IFCJ0E3CU078EI03IF8,M0IFEJ0FFCU07FEI07IF,M07IFJ07FV01FCI0IFE,M03IF8I01EW0FI01IFC,M01IFC"
Print #1, "gL03IF8,N0IFEgL07IF,N07IFgL0IFE,N03IF8gJ01IFC,N01IFCgJ03IF8,O0IFEgJ07IF,O07IFgJ0IFE,O03IF8gH01IFC,O01IFCgH03IF8,P0IFEgH07IF,P07IFgH0IFE,P03IF8g01IFC,P"
Print #1, "01IFCg03IF8,Q0IFEg07IF,Q07IFg0IFE,Q03IF8X01IFC,Q01IFCX03IF8,R0IFEX07IF,R07IFX0IFE,R03IF8V01IFC,R01IFCV03IF8,S0IFEV07IF,S07IFV0IFE,S03IF8T01IFC,S01IFCT"
Print #1, "03IF8,T0IFET07IF,T07IFT0IFE,T03IF8R01IFC,T01IFCR03IF8,U0IFER07IF,U07IFR0IFE,U03IF8P01IFC,U01IFCP03IF8,V0IFEP07IF,V07IFP0IFE,V03IF8N01IFC,V01IFCN03IF8,"
Print #1, "W0IFEN07IF,W07IFN0IFE,W03IF8L01IFC,W01IFCL03IF8,X0IFEL07IF,X07IFL0IFE,X03IF8J01IFC,X01IFCJ03IF8,Y0IFEJ07IF,Y07IFJ0IFE,Y03IF8001IFC,Y01IFC003IF8,g0IFE0"
Print #1, "07IF,g07IF00IFE,g03IF81IFC,g01IFC3IF8,gG0IFE7IF,gG07LFE,gG03LFC,gG01LF8,gH0LF,gH07JFE,gH03JFC,gH01JF8,gI0JF,gI07FFE,gI03FFC,gI01FF8,gJ0FF,gJ07E,gJ03C,"
Print #1, "gJ018,,^FS"
Print #1, "^XZ"
```

If I run the code wide-open, the first image prints and the second one doesn't. If step into the code and skip the first image and continue the run at the second image, the second image prints.

If I move this code directly into the Online Viewer at [labelary.com](https://www.labelary.com) (after removing the `Print #1,` and all of the double-quotes), both images print correctly.

It appears that there is something about transitioning between the first image field separator (^FS) and the field origin (^FO) of the second image that's causing trouble for the ZPL Printer emulator.

Also (to handle any suggestions that I just load the images to the printer and skip this crazy HEX method), the reason I'm having to do it the HEX way is because A) the printer I want to print to is hundreds of miles away (I do not currently have the ability to upload GRF images to it with ZebraNet Bridge) and B) the ZPL Printer emulator does not have the ability to store graphics files (there is no functional E drive on which I can store images to be called in by the program using `^IM` or `^XG`).

Here is the [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zpl-printer/phoidlklenidapnijkabnfdgmadlcmjo) to the ZPL Printer plug-in for those interested.

Update...to eliminate the possibility that this issue was related to the fact that I'm sending the ZPL II to the emulator with VBA, I created the same code in Notepad and printed from there. Same result...one image prints.

Again, if I paste the code into the Online Viewer on labelary.com, I correctly get two images.

```
^XA^FO0,0^GFA,5000,5000,25,,gJ018,gJ03C,gJ07E,gJ0FF,gI01FF8,gI03FFC,gI07FFE,gI0JF,gH01JF8,gH03JFC,gH07JFE,gH0LF,gG01LF8,gG03LFC,gG07LFE,gG0IFE7IF,g01IFC3IF8,g03IF81IFC,g07IF00IFE,g0IFE007IF,Y01IFC003IF8,Y03IF8001IFC,Y07IFJ0IFE,Y0IFEJ07IF,X01IFCJ03IF8,X03IF8J01IFC,X07IFL0IFE,X0IFEL07IF,W01IFCL03IF8,W03IF8L01IFC,W07IFN0IFE,W0IFEN07IF,V01IFCN03IF8,V03IF8N01IFC,V07IFP0IFE,V0IFEP07IF,U01IFCP03IF8,U03IF8P01IFC,U07IFR0IFE,U0IFER07IF,T01IFCL08K03IF8,T03IF8K018K01IFC,T07IFL018L0IFE,T0IFEL018L07IF,S01IFCL038L03IF8,S03IF8L038L01IFC,S07IFM03CM0IFE,S0IFEM03CM07IF,R01IFCM07CM03IF8,R03IF8M07EM01IFC,R07IFN07EN0IFE,R0IFEN07FN07IF,Q01IFCN07FN03IF8,Q03IF8N07F8M01IFC,Q07IFO07F8N0IFE,Q0IFEO07FCN07IF,P01IFCO07FEN03IF8,P03IF8O07FEN01IFC,P07IFP07FFO0IFE,P0IFEL01C007FFO07IF,O01IFCL01E007FF002L03IF8,O03IF8L01F007FF803L01IFC,O07IFM01F007FF803M0IFE,O0IFEM01F807FF8038L07IF,N01IFCM01F807FFC038L03IF8,N03IF8M01FC07FFC03CL01IFC,N07IFN01FC07FFC03CM0IFE,N0IFEN03FC0IFE03CM07IF,M01IFCN03FC0IFE03CM03IF8,M03IF8N03FC0IFE07EM01IFC,M07IFO03FC0IFE07EN0IFE,M0IFEO03FE1IFE07EN07IF,L01IFCM0803FE1JF07EN03IF8,L03IF8M0C03FF3IFE0FEN01IFC,L07IFN0E03FF3IFE0FEO0IFE,L0IFEN0F03LFE1FEO07IF,K01IFCN0703LFE3FEO03IF8,K03IF8N0783LFE7FE02M01IFC,K07IFO07C3OFE03N0IFE,K0IFEO07C3OFE07N07IF,J01IFCO07E3OFE07N03IF8,J03IF8O07F3OFE0F8M01IFC,J07IFP07F9OFE1F8N0IFE,J0IFEP07LF7JFC3F8N07IF,I01IFCP07LF3JFC7F8N03IF8,I03IF8P07LF1JFCFF8N01IFC,I07IFQ07LF0JFBFFCO0IFE,I0IFEQ07LF07LFCO07IF,001IFCQ07LF07LFCO03IF8,003IF8Q07LF03LF8O01IFC,007IFR03LF01LF8P0IFE,00IFER03LF01LF8P07IF,01IFCO01003KFE01LF8P03IF8,03IF8O01801KFE00LFQ01IFC,07IFQ0C01KFE00LFR0IFE,0IFEQ0E01KFC00LFR07IF,1IFCQ0F00KFC00KFER03IF83IF8Q0F80KFC007JFER01IFC7IFR0FC07JF8007JFC08Q0IFE7IFR07E07JF8007JF808Q0IFE3IF8Q07FE3FF7F8007FDFF818P01IFC1IFCQ07KF7F8007F9FF078P03IF80IFEQ03KF7F8007F9FE3F8P07IF,07IFQ03KF3F8007F1JF8P0IFE,03IF8P03JFE1F8007C1JF8O01IFC,01IFCP03JFE0F800781JFP03IF8,00IFEP01JFE07800603JFP07IF,007IFP01KF01800403JFP0IFE,003IF8O01KF00400403JFO01IFC,001IFCP0KFM07JFO03IF8,I0IFEP0KF8L07IFEO07IF,I07IFP0KF8L07IFEO0IFE,I03IF8O0KFCL0JFEN01IFC,I01IFCO07FFBFEK01JFCN03IF8,J0IFEO07FFDFEK01FDFFCN07IF,J07IFO03FFC7FK03F9FFCN0IFE,J03IF8N03FFE038J07C3FF8M01IFC,J01IFCN01FFEO03FF8M03IF8,K0IFEN01IFO07FFN07IF,K07IFO0IFO0IFN0IFE,K03IF8N0IF8N0FFEM01IFC,K01IFCN07FF8M01FFCM03IF8,L0IFEN03FFCM03FFCM07IF,L07IFO0FFEM07FF8M0IFE,L03IF8N07FFM0FFEM01IFC,L01IFCN01FF8K01FFCM03IF8,M0IFEO07FCK03FFN07IF,M07IFO01FFK07FCN0IFE,M03IF8O03FCI01FFN01IFC,M01IFCQ0FC003F8N03IF8,N0IFEgL07IF,N07IFgL0IFE,N03IF8gJ01IFC,N01IFCgJ03IF8,O0IFEgJ07IF,O07IFgJ0IFE,O03IF8J0UFI01IFC,O01IFCJ0UFI03IF8,P0IFEJ0UFI07IF,P07IFJ0UFI0IFE,P03IF8I0UF001IFC,P01IFCI0UF003IF8,Q0IFEg07IF,Q07IFg0IFE,Q03IF8X01IFC,Q01IFCX03IF8,R0IFEX07IF,R07IFX0IFE,R03IF8V01IFC,R01IFCV03IF8,S0IFEV07IF,S07IFV0IFE,S03IF8T01IFC,S01IFCT03IF8,T0IFET07IF,T07IFT0IFE,T03IF8R01IFC,T01IFCR03IF8,U0IFER07IF,U07IFR0IFE,U03IF8P01IFC,U01IFCP03IF8,V0IFEP07IF,V07IFP0IFE,V03IF8N01IFC,V01IFCN03IF8,W0IFEN07IF,W07IFN0IFE,W03IF8L01IFC,W01IFCL03IF8,X0IFEL07IF,X07IFL0IFE,X03IF8J01IFC,X01IFCJ03IF8,Y0IFEJ07IF,Y07IFJ0IFE,Y03IF8001IFC,Y01IFC003IF8,g0IFE007IF,g07IF00IFE,g03IF81IFC,g01IFC3IF8,gG0IFE7IF,gG07LFE,gG03LFC,gG01LF8,gH0LF,gH07JFE,gH03JFC,gH01JF8,gI0JF,gI07FFE,gI03FFC,gI01FF8,gJ0FF,gJ07E,gJ03C,gJ018,,^FS^FO500,500^GFA,5000,5000,25,,gJ018,gJ03C,gJ07E,gJ0FF,gI01FF8,gI03FFC,gI07FFE,gI0JF,gH01JF8,gH03JFC,gH07JFE,gH0LF,gG01LF8,gG03LFC,gG07LFE,gG0IFE7IF,g01IFC3IF8,g03IF81IFC,g07IF00IFE,g0IFE007IF,Y01IFC003IF8,Y03IF8001IFC,Y07IFJ0IFE,Y0IFEJ07IF,X01IFCJ03IF8,X03IF8J01IFC,X07IFL0IFE,X0IFEL07IF,W01IFCL03IF8,W03IF8L01IFC,W07IFN0IFE,W0IFEN07IF,V01IFCN03IF8,V03IF8N01IFC,V07IFP0IFE,V0IFEP07IF,U01IFCP03IF8,U03IF8P01IFC,U07IFR0IFE,U0IFER07IF,T01IFCL08K03IF8,T03IF8K018K01IFC,T07IFL018L0IFE,T0IFEL018L07IF,S01IFCL038L03IF8,S03IF8L038L01IFC,S07IFM03CM0IFE,S0IFEM03CM07IF,R01IFCM07CM03IF8,R03IF8M07EM01IFC,R07IFN07EN0IFE,R0IFEN07FN07IF,Q01IFCN07FN03IF8,Q03IF8N07F8M01IFC,Q07IFO07F8N0IFE,Q0IFEO07FCN07IF,P01IFCO07FEN03IF8,P03IF8O07FEN01IFC,P07IFP07FFO0IFE,P0IFEL01C007FFO07IF,O01IFCL01E007FF002L03IF8,O03IF8L01F007FF803L01IFC,O07IFM01F007FF803M0IFE,O0IFEM01F807FF8038L07IF,N01IFCM01F807FFC038L03IF8,N03IF8M01FC07FFC03CL01IFC,N07IFN01FC07FFC03CM0IFE,N0IFEN03FC0IFE03CM07IF,M01IFCN03FC0IFE03CM03IF8,M03IF8N03FC0IFE07EM01IFC,M07IFO03FC0IFE07EN0IFE,M0IFEO03FE1IFE07EN07IF,L01IFCM0803FE1JF07EN03IF8,L03IF8M0C03FF3IFE0FEN01IFC,L07IFN0E03FF3IFE0FEO0IFE,L0IFEN0F03LFE1FEO07IF,K01IFCN0703LFE3FEO03IF8,K03IF8N0783LFE7FE02M01IFC,K07IFO07C3OFE03N0IFE,K0IFEO07C3OFE07N07IF,J01IFCO07E3OFE07N03IF8,J03IF8O07F3OFE0F8M01IFC,J07IFP07F9OFE1F8N0IFE,J0IFEP07LF7JFC3F8N07IF,I01IFCP07LF3JFC7F8N03IF8,I03IF8P07LF1JFCFF8N01IFC,I07IFQ07LF0JFBFFCO0IFE,I0IFEQ07LF07LFCO07IF,001IFCQ07LF07LFCO03IF8,003IF8Q07LF03LF8O01IFC,007IFR03LF01LF8P0IFE,00IFER03LF01LF8P07IF,01IFCO01003KFE01LF8P03IF8,03IF8O01801KFE00LFQ01IFC,07IFQ0C01KFE00LFR0IFE,0IFEQ0E01KFC00LFR07IF,1IFCQ0F00KFC00KFER03IF83IF8Q0F80KFC007JFER01IFC7IFR0FC07JF8007JFC08Q0IFE7IFR07E07JF8007JF808Q0IFE3IF8Q07FE3FF7F8007FDFF818P01IFC1IFCQ07KF7F8007F9FF078P03IF80IFEQ03KF7F8007F9FE3F8P07IF,07IFQ03KF3F8007F1JF8P0IFE,03IF8P03JFE1F8007C1JF8O01IFC,01IFCP03JFE0F800781JFP03IF8,00IFEP01JFE07800603JFP07IF,007IFP01KF01800403JFP0IFE,003IF8O01KF00400403JFO01IFC,001IFCP0KFM07JFO03IF8,I0IFEP0KF8L07IFEO07IF,I07IFP0KF8L07IFEO0IFE,I03IF8O0KFCL0JFEN01IFC,I01IFCO07FFBFEK01JFCN03IF8,J0IFEO07FFDFEK01FDFFCN07IF,J07IFO03FFC7FK03F9FFCN0IFE,J03IF8N03FFE038J07C3FF8M01IFC,J01IFCN01FFEO03FF8M03IF8,K0IFEN01IFO07FFN07IF,K07IFO0IFO0IFN0IFE,K03IF8N0IF8N0FFEM01IFC,K01IFCN07FF8M01FFCM03IF8,L0IFEN03FFCM03FFCM07IF,L07IFO0FFEM07FF8M0IFE,L03IF8N07FFM0FFEM01IFC,L01IFCN01FF8K01FFCM03IF8,M0IFEO07FCK03FFN07IF,M07IFO01FFK07FCN0IFE,M03IF8O03FCI01FFN01IFC,M01IFCQ0FC003F8N03IF8,N0IFEgL07IF,N07IFgL0IFE,N03IF8gJ01IFC,N01IFCgJ03IF8,O0IFEgJ07IF,O07IFgJ0IFE,O03IF8J0UFI01IFC,O01IFCJ0UFI03IF8,P0IFEJ0UFI07IF,P07IFJ0UFI0IFE,P03IF8I0UF001IFC,P01IFCI0UF003IF8,Q0IFEg07IF,Q07IFg0IFE,Q03IF8X01IFC,Q01IFCX03IF8,R0IFEX07IF,R07IFX0IFE,R03IF8V01IFC,R01IFCV03IF8,S0IFEV07IF,S07IFV0IFE,S03IF8T01IFC,S01IFCT03IF8,T0IFET07IF,T07IFT0IFE,T03IF8R01IFC,T01IFCR03IF8,U0IFER07IF,U07IFR0IFE,U03IF8P01IFC,U01IFCP03IF8,V0IFEP07IF,V07IFP0IFE,V03IF8N01IFC,V01IFCN03IF8,W0IFEN07IF,W07IFN0IFE,W03IF8L01IFC,W01IFCL03IF8,X0IFEL07IF,X07IFL0IFE,X03IF8J01IFC,X01IFCJ03IF8,Y0IFEJ07IF,Y07IFJ0IFE,Y03IF8001IFC,Y01IFC003IF8,g0IFE007IF,g07IF00IFE,g03IF81IFC,g01IFC3IF8,gG0IFE7IF,gG07LFE,gG03LFC,gG01LF8,gH0LF,gH07JFE,gH03JFC,gH01JF8,gI0JF,gI07FFE,gI03FFC,gI01FF8,gJ0FF,gJ07E,gJ03C,gJ018,,^FS^XZ
```

update...when I send this from VBA to my USB-connected GX430T, I correctly get two images. I think there may be a bug in the code that drives the "ZPL Printer" emulator. If anybody out there can get this to work properly in the emulator, please answer.

[image: two images on one label]

Comment: What happens when you put each image in its own ``^XA ... ^XZ`` section?

Comment: Wouldn't that print two labels? I need both images on the same label.

Comment: updated question with picture

Comment: On labelary.com my suggestion does not work, only the first image is shown! :-(

Comment: If you have multiple labels in the code (i.e. if the `Labels Available` value is > 1, you can visualize each by changing the value in the `Show Label` field.